# Typescript 2345 on RXJS Operators

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Recently, I've been seeing a lot of typescript transpile errors in my codebase. I'm not sure when it started but the main thing is, the code still runs fine. There's absolutely no change in the logic of the application. One of the most peculiar things I observed in my codebase is this particular example.

```
 combineLatest(of(1), of(2))
   .subscribe(([a,b]: [number, number]) => {
     console.log(a, b);
   });
```

This throws TS2345 error. It says something alone the line of

`[a,b] of type [number, number] => null is not assignable to type value of type [Observable<number>, Observable<number>] => null`

Why does it say that? When I log a and b, all I'm seeing are 1 and 2. I don't see an instance of an Observable.

If it helps, I also have an Angular library npm linked with my web application.

running ng version procures:

```
*Angular CLI: 8.2.1
Node: 10.15.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.1
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.802.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.802.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.802.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.802.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.2.1
@angular/cdk                      8.0.2
@angular/http                     7.2.15
@ngtools/webpack                  8.2.1
@nguniversal/express-engine       8.1.1
@schematics/angular               8.2.1
@schematics/update                0.802.1
rxjs                              6.5.2
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.38.0*
```

Comment: What version of angular are you using? and typescript?

Comment: No problem here https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5sd9hp

Comment: exactly, right? I don't see the issue in another one of my web applications that does not have a npm linked Angular library.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to RxJS 6? Could it be an import issue?

Comment: I did not. All the creation imports are from 'rxjs' and all pipeable operators are from 'rxjs/operators'. So, I made some changes over the weekend that made the errors go away. I started packaging my Angular library with ng-packagr and soon as I installed the newer version of the shared library, all the transpile errors went away. Really weird and disappointing to not find a root cause. :(

Comment: Do you get the same error if you downgrade rxjs? `npm install rxjs@6.4.0` The reason I ask is that the `6.5.0` release changed the definition order of the `combineLatest` functions from `6.4.0` to better declare depreciation of some forms of that function. I have a feeling you're picking up on a side effect of this change.

Comment: If downgrading to `6.4.0` fixes the problem, then I would switch it back and not worry about it, because once they remove the deprecated functions the side effect should go away. TypeScript is likely getting confused by one of the deprecated arguments that are still defined in the library.

Comment: @Reactgular: I did have some deprecation warnings earlier and all I had to do was wrap my observables that went in the combineLatest() in an array. That seemed to do the trick. I believe I had the transpile issues before I upgraded all my libraries. I run ncu -u once a month to update every dependencies. I remember it being there before I upgraded from 6.4 to 6.5. I never got around to posting a stackoverflow question about it until Aug 9.